# Term store: There was an error processing request

Tags: term-store

I get error message

> There was an error processing request

when I do below task:

```
   Site Collection > Site Settings > Term Store Management
```

or

when I edit document properties and try to resolve people picker.

This is term store error. Can you please help me with solution?

There is no NLB configuration due to which server load exceed and error occurs sometimes. Can anyone provide me alternative to overcome this re-occurring error.

Comment: Are there any ULS Logs generated when this error occurs?

Comment: Due to some issue we cannot check log error. Any alternative to resolve this error?

Comment: The ULS Log will probably give a more detailed error log. This will help immensely with troubleshooting. Could you verify if there are recent log files located in the default ULS Log file location: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14"

Comment: Can you reach the term store from central admin? Are you using multiple managed metadata services?